# How to parse android-php json webservice response

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, android-emulator

I am new to android and studying a bit. I am in a hard duty to pass json objects between android and php.

I have this code to send json object to send json object to server. Its pretty working well. Its printing in Toast also. But Can any please help me how to read and show the response from my server to my application ?

my code looks like

```
package com.test.webservice;


import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        String path = "http://www.mysite.com/app.php";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                // Limit
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
            json.put("service", "GOOGLE");
            json.put("name", "My Name");
            Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
            post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding((Header) new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            /* Checking response */
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                    // data in
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // entity
                String a = convertStreamToString(in);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by showing the response? You mean to code at php so that it should return json?

Comment: thanks for your comment ... No not the php code ... I mean the response from php and parse it to array and to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if you have an array called `response` on your `php` side like below and then I assume you are populating data into that array in this way:

```
$response = array();
$response["intvalue"] = 1234;
$response["stringmessage"] = "Data from the server";

echo json_encode($response);// Here you are echoing json response. So in the inputstream you would get the json data. You need to extract it over there and can display according to your requirement.
```

**Extraction at android side:**

Here you need to convert the String(which you are displaying in the toast) to json object in the below way:

```
JSONObject json = stringToJsonobj(a);  // a is your string response

int passedinteger = json.getInt("intvalue");
String passedStringValue = json.getString("stringmessage");

public JSONObject stringToJsonobj(String result)
    {
        JSONObject jObj = null;
            try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(result);          

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }

         return jObj; 
}
```

In this way, you can get an `individual values(passedinteger, passedstringvalue)` and display on whatever views you want. Hope this helps